# Closure of a Herman Ring

Tags: general-topology, dynamical-systems

In the paper on the [Theorem of Kerekjarto](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0303256.pdf), it says

"However, the closure of a bounded open set which is homeomorphic to the open unit disc is not necessarily a closed topological disc" (page 2).

It refers to chapter 15 (on Herman Rings) of "[Dynamics in one complex variable](https://b-ok.cc/book/2310316/6df984)" by Milnor. I couldn't find a direct proof of this proposition but lemma 15.7 says:

"If U is a Herman ring, then every boundary
point of U belongs to the closure of the orbit of some critical
point. The boundary $\partial U$ has two connected components, each
of which is an infinite set."

From this, I assume that a Herman ring is homeomorphic to an open disk but its closure has two connected components, so it can't be homeomorphic to a closed topological disk. Is this correct?

Comment: Are you just looking for an example of such open set? Or does it have to be about Herman rings?

Comment: I'm looking for an example of such open set. The article referenced the chapter on Herman Rings, which I still need to get familiar to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $U = \{(x, y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 : 1 < x^2+y^2 < 2\}\setminus (\mathbb{R}_+\times\{0\})$ be a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

[image]

This looks something like in the picture here and is homeomorphic to the open unit disc.

But as you see, its closure is $\overline{U} = \{(x, y) : 1\leq x^2+y^2\leq 2\}$, which is not homeomorphic with closed disc because, for example, it's homotopic to the circle $S^1 = \{(x, y) : x^2+y^2 = 1\}$, while the closed disc isn't.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you